# Slow running Loop. Looking to find way to execute multiple records per execute

Tags: sql, excel, vba, loops

I have an excel workbook that contains about 5,000 rows of data.  I have two buttons mapped to macros. One button will delete all data in the table, and reinsert it from the Excel Workbook, and the other will only insert the 'new' rows based on a unique ID.

I am finding that both of these buttons are taking a long time to run. ~10-15 minutes.  Right now, it is performing the insert for every row, but I am looking to combine this.

Basically, I would like to loop through ~100 or so rows then insert. Then loop through the next hundred rows and insert.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. VBA / Coding in general is not my forte and i'm pulling a brick wall on this one.

Thanks!

```
Sub Rebuild_Click()

' ***********************
' ** Declare Variables **
' ***********************
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim sSTATUS, sCHANNEL, sISSUE, sLOB, sDESC, sIN, sJN, sIS, sPRIME, sIU, sTR, sAU As String
    Dim answer, sQTY, sRRSC, sOA, sMeetings, sOutages As Integer
    Dim sDATE As Date
    With Sheets("OASYS ADMIN TRACKER")

' ****************************
' ** Show Information Popup **
' ****************************
        answer = MsgBox("You are about to update the database with ~5,000 records." & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "This will take approximately 5 minutes." & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "If you wish to continue, please press Yes. Otherwise, Press No" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "----------" & vbCrLf & "EXCEL IS NOT FROZEN." & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "****DO NOT CLOSE EXCEL ****", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Update Database")

' ***********************
' ** Open IF Statement **
' ***********************
        If answer = vbYes Then

            ' ***********************
            ' ** Connection String **
            ' ***********************
                conn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Password=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=SupportAdmin;Data Source=tcp:XXXXX;"

            ' *************************
            ' ** Purge Existing Data **
            ' *************************
                conn.Execute "Delete FROM dbo.TestDB"

            ' *********************
            ' ** Skip Leader Row **
            ' *********************
                iRowNo = 4

            ' ************************
            ' ** Begin Dataset Loop **
            ' ************************
                Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 3) = ""
                    sID = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
                    sSTATUS = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
                    sDATE = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
                    sCHANNEL = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
                    sISSUE = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
                    sQTY = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)
                    sLOB = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)
                    sDESC = .Cells(iRowNo, 8)
                    sIN = .Cells(iRowNo, 9)
                    sJN = .Cells(iRowNo, 10)
                    sIS = .Cells(iRowNo, 11)
                    sPRIME = .Cells(iRowNo, 12)
                    sIU = .Cells(iRowNo, 13)
                    sTR = .Cells(iRowNo, 14)
                    sAU = .Cells(iRowNo, 15)
                    sRRSC = .Cells(iRowNo, 16)
                    sOA = .Cells(iRowNo, 17)
                    sOutages = .Cells(iRowNo, 18)
                    sMeetings = .Cells(iRowNo, 19)

            ' ***********************
            ' ** Replace ' in Data **
            ' ***********************
                sDESC = Replace(sDESC, "'", "''")
                sIS = Replace(sIS, "'", "''")
                sIU = Replace(sIU, "'", "''")

            ' *****************
            ' ** Execute SQL **
            ' *****************
                conn.Execute "insert into dbo.TestDB (ID,STATUS,DATE,CHANNEL,ISSUE,QTY,LOB,[DESC],[IN],JN,[IS],PRIME,IU,TR,AU,RRSC,OA,OUTAGES,MEETINGS) " & _
                             "values ('" & sID & "','" & sSTATUS & "', '" & sDATE & "','" & sCHANNEL & "', '" & sISSUE & "', '" & sQTY & "', '" & sLOB & "', '" & sDESC & "', '" & sIN & "', '" & sJN & "', '" & sIS & "', '" & sPRIME & "', '" & sIU & "', '" & sTR & "', '" & sAU & "', '" & sRRSC & "', '" & sOA & "', '" & sOutages & "', '" & sMeetings & "')"

                iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
             Loop

' ****************************
' ** Show Information Popup **
' ****************************
        MsgBox "Database Update Complete!"

' *****************************
' ** Close Connection String **
' *****************************
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

' ****************************
' ** Close IF Statement **
' ****************************
        Else
           ' do nothing
     End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: *"Basically, I would like to loop through ~100 or so rows then insert. Then loop through the next hundred rows and insert. "* Using a Transaction also might speed things up and COMMIT after that number of records..

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code with makeshift table in local SQL Server 2005 and found taking only 10 seconds for around 5000 records. In your case the delay may be due to Database Size, network speed etc.

However after trying it with code to insert 100 records at a time the same time reduced to 1 odd second only.

```
Sub test2()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, iRowNo As Long, DataArr As Variant
Dim SqStr As String, ValStr As String, Rw As Long, Cl As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet, tm As Double
tm = Timer

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;;Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS"
conn.Execute "Delete FROM dbo.Test"

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
iRowNo = 4
LastRow = Ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DataArr = Ws.Range("A" & iRowNo & ":S" & LastRow)
LastCol = UBound(DataArr, 2)

SqStr = "insert into dbo.Test (ID,STATUS,DATE,CHANNEL,ISSUE,QTY,LOB,[DESC],[IN],JN,[IS],PRIME,IU,TR,AU,RRSC,OA,OUTAGES,MEETINGS) "
'Sqlstr=Sqlstr & " Values "  'May use for Sql Server 2008 and above

    For Rw = 1 To UBound(DataArr, 1)
    DataArr(Rw, 1) = Replace(DataArr(Rw, 1), "'", "''")
    DataArr(Rw, 8) = Replace(DataArr(Rw, 8), "'", "''")
    DataArr(Rw, 13) = Replace(DataArr(Rw, 13), "'", "''")
    'ValStr = ValStr & "('"   'May use for Sql Server 2008 and above
    ValStr = ValStr & "Select '"
        For Cl = 1 To UBound(DataArr, 2)
        'ValStr = ValStr & DataArr(Rw, Cl) & IIf(Cl < LastCol, "','", "')")  'May use for Sql Server 2008 and above
        ValStr = ValStr & DataArr(Rw, Cl) & IIf(Cl < LastCol, "','", "'")   ' Used for test in Sql Server 2005
        Next Cl

        If Rw Mod 100 = 0 Then  ' exceute at 100 records
        ValStr = SqStr & ValStr
        conn.Execute ValStr
        DoEvents
        ValStr = ""
        Debug.Print Rw, Timer - tm
        Else
            If Rw < UBound(DataArr, 1) Then
            'ValStr = ValStr & ", "  'Modify Comma / Space between datasets of two rows according Sql version Syntax
            ValStr = ValStr & " UNION ALL "  'Used for test with Sql Server 2005.
            End If
        End If
    Next Rw

    If Rw Mod 100 > 0 Then
    ValStr = SqStr & ValStr
    conn.Execute ValStr
    DoEvents
    ValStr = ""
    Debug.Print Rw, Timer - tm
    End If


Debug.Print "Total Seconds Taken: " & Timer - tm
End Sub
```

The INSERT SQl syntax along with connection string etc may please be modified for the type & version used by you along with suggestion in @Raymond Nijland's comment.